# MongoDB exposed as REST with SpringBoot: what is the return object type

Tags: mongodb, rest, spring-boot

By exposing a collection of MongoDB as a REST service with SpringBoot, I'm getting back such a document when doing an HTTP GET on the service

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/people
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/search"
    }
  },
 "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "firstName" : "Frodo",
      "lastName" : "Baggins",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/53149b8e3004990b1af9f229"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

The People contained in the collection are in the "_embedded" part.

I'd like to use simply a list of People, so what is the URL to use? Alternatively, what is the object type of this returned document so that I can deserialise it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are only rest endpoints available on Spring Mongo data rest API.

```
{[/{people}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]
{[/{people}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{{/{people}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/ || ],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/ || ],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/ || ],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}
{[/{people}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}
{[/{people}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
{[/{people}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}
```

We can get a person document if we know _id of that particular document.

We can get only `_embedded` json object using search api. For example,

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

      List<Person> findAllByIdIsNotNull();

}
```

As `_id` won't be null in MongoDB, we can get all the documents if we hit this endpoint `http://localhost:8080/people/search/findAllByIdIsNotNull`. The response would be as below.

```
{
 "_embedded": {
    "people": [{
            "firstName": "N1",
            "lastName": "N2",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/people/59d54d2bb13148a7e93953c8"
                },
                "person": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/people/59d54d2bb13148a7e93953c8"
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

The best way to get only person documents is by using some json parsing apis like `jq` in shell script or gson/jackson in java etc.

Hope this helps.